# How to combine two Adruino Sketches into one

Tags: arduino

I am doing a project using sensors (LDR & Ultrasonic) and LEDs using the Arduino Software. I have managed to get the light bulb to work, however I would like to know on how to combine two different Arduino programs into one. Attached below are the two different programs

Program 1:

```
int ldr=A0;//Set A0(Analog Input) for LDR.
int value=0;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
value=analogRead(ldr);//Reads the Value of LDR(light).
Serial.println("LDR value is :");//Prints the value of LDR to Serial Monitor.
Serial.println(value);
if(value<300)
  {
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);//Makes the LED glow in Dark.
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(3,LOW);//Turns the LED OFF in Light.
  }
}
```

Program 2:

```
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12 
#define led 11
void setup() 
{ Serial.begin (9600); 
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); 
pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
}
void loop() 
{ long duration, distance; 
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
delayMicroseconds(2); 
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); 
delayMicroseconds(10); 
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); 
distance = (duration/2) / 29.1; 
if (distance < 10) 
{ digitalWrite(led,HIGH); 
} 
else { 
digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
} 
Serial.print(distance); 
Serial.println(" cm"); 
delay(500); 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How to combine them depends entirely on what exactly you are trying to achieve as an end result, which is far from clear. But you probably just need to split each `loop()` function into another one with a name that says what it does, then call them both from `loop()`, perhaps only calling one of them whenever then appropriate delay has passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer and each 500 milliseconds run loop2
The first loop run normaly but the second loop run each 500 milliseconds

```
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
#define led 11
#define DELAY 500
int ldr = A0; //Set A0(Analog Input) for LDR.
int value = 0;
long timer = millis(); // a timer for timing 500 milliseconds

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  value = analogRead(ldr); //Reads the Value of LDR(light).
  Serial.println("LDR value is :");//Prints the value of LDR to Serial Monitor.
  Serial.println(value);
  if (value < 300)
  {
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH); //Makes the LED glow in Dark.
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(3, LOW); //Turns the LED OFF in Light.
  }

  if (millis() - timer >= DELAY ) {
    timer = millis();//reset timer
    loop2();
  }
}


void loop2() {
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;
  if (distance < 10)
  { digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm");
}
```

Comment: What did you do with the original code, and how does that answer the question? Code without context doesn't make for a good answer usually. More specifically: Just jamming the two `loop()`s together doesn't seem right. Now you `delay(500)` between each `analogRead(ldr)` and corresponding `digitalWrite(3, ...)`, whereas that loop originally span as fast as possible without delays. This is why I said it requires thought to combine them.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I edit my answer